# Finding the value of an exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking at how to find the exponent $x$ in a couple equations

$2^x=16$ I know the answer is $4$ but how do I get it? the second similar is $10^x=143.7$

Comment: Do you know about logarithms?

Comment: At most I know how to convert exp to log form and back, but have not done much else beyond that.

Comment: Then you should be able to write down that $$10^x = 143.7 \iff \log_{10} 143.7 = x$$ This is a valid exact answer; if you want a decimal approximation, use a calculator (it's somewhere between $2$ and $3$).

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  2^x &= 16 \\
  2^x &= 2^4 \\
  x &= 4
\end{align*}

$$ \text{OR} $$

\begin{align*}
  2^x &= 16 \\
  \log_{2}{2^x} &= \log_{2}{16} \\
  x \log_{2}{2} &= 4 \\
  x &= 4
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first it's obvious that $16=2^4$ and therefore $x=4$. However, for the second question you'd have to use *logs*.

$$\log_ab=c \implies a^c=b$$

This is the definition of a log. Hence when you have $10^x=143.7$, we can rewrite that as:$$\log_{10}143.7=x$$
Now this isn't just so that it looks nicer. There is a property of logs that can help you solve this. Remember this rule:

$$\log_ab=\frac{\log_{n}b}{\log_{n}a}$$

Where $n$ is *any* number. Most commonly, you'd use $10$ (which is your `log` button on your calculator) or $e$ (which is the natural log, `ln`).

For this, I'll just use the natural log for demonstrative purposes (because this particular example is already base $10$). And so we have:

$$x=\log_{10}143.7=\frac{\ln 143.7}{\ln 10}\approx 2.1575$$